# Old VS2008 ASP.NET web site project doesn't update DLL in bin after building

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have inherited an old ASP.NET web site project (not a web project), so it uses the web site model from what I gather.  There is no code in the App_Code folder. There are dozens of aspx and aspx.cs files in a different folder.

What I have done so far:

1. I have copied the entire project locally from the previous person's fileshare (he's gone and didn't use TFS).
2. I loaded the web site in VS2008, made a small change to an email address in the code and rebuilt it.
   At this point, it compiles fine, no errors.  But the dlls in the bin folder do not reflect the proper date/time stamp.  I published the site to the test server and it is still using the previous email address before I updated it.

My problem: Why would the dll not get updated?  I have read there is a difference between a web site model and a web application model.  When I select Build from the menu, it actually says "Build Web Site", and not the project name.  This is my first experience using this type of project.

My Question: Any ideas what I can do to resolve?   I have already combed through similar questions on this site but the ones that are closest to my issue don't have resolve/answered status.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried deleting the DLLs in the bin folder and then rebuild your application?

Comment: I did.  But it blew it up.  Got all sorts of errors related to the Global.asax and Global.asax.cs files.  I had to completely delete the project and download it again locally.

Comment: I just read somewhere that web sites (vs. web projects) do not build dlls, but are precompiled in some way.  That doesn't make sense to me.  This project has a bin folder and a dll in it with the same name as the project, so it was built at some point (but the date stamp is 3 years ago).  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, didn't websites perform runtime compilation and hence not generate a dll? Don't quote me on that though, it's been a while. Could you convert it to a web application from VS?

Comment: That's what is strange.  There is a bin folder and a DLL in there already.  Where did it come from then? This is a long standing app that has been stable forever.  I really just want to make a minor change.  I don't want to blow it up...this is my 2nd day on the job :-)

Comment: And just to confirm, it *does* build without error.  And I published to the IIS site without error.  It's just that my updates aren't reflected in the test site after publishing, which led me to believe this old dll was the issue.  Could I be going down an invalid path?

Comment: Do you see .compiled files in the folder?

Comment: I ended up copying everything file by file to another web application project and recompiling.  I don't know what was wrong with the other one.  In the new project it didn't even compile because of various errors, none of which popped up when building the original.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a solution with at least two projects:

```
Sln
- Website
- DLL
```

On the `Website` add a reference to the `DLL` and build.  Should take care of it.

Alternatively you could convert to a Web Application as well, but you'd have the same problem if your project structure is not correct.